# Js Imformation does not exist on external property

Tags: genexus

I'm trying to load a javascript file that I wrote on GeneXus.
I found the external object that we can load other file on GeneXus.
So I was trying to load mine as seeing this page.
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31075,How+to+execute+GeneXus+events+from+JS+code+using+External+Objects,

But there is not Javascript  Imformation  on external property of my enviroment.
Does it need some setting and will it appear?

Please help me.
My GeneXus is Evolution3
Version is 10.3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the JS file name in "Javascript External name" property. Then, in the Events level, you can create sub-levels based on each method you have in your JS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your message.

I know I have to specify the file name.

But there is not the property.

I mean we could see "Javascript External name" property on Javascript Information on your GeneXus.

However, this property doesn't appear on mine.

Some property, such as .Net Information, Java Information, Ruby Information, are displaying as same as yours.

There's Javascript Information below Android Information on yours.

But There is Blackberry Information below Android Information on mine.

There isn't  Javascript Information and "Javascript External name" property.

How can I do that?